# Deserializing serialized objects with gsoap in order to validate web service output

Tags: c++, gsoap

Out of the box, gsoap does not provide any means for output validation (ensure schema validity of object serializations sent to the client).  We already had some validation issues in the past so at least I'd like to  validate our web service output through unit testing.

The idea is pretty simple.  Put together an arbitrary object tree using gsoap-mapped C++ types and pass it to a generic function

```
template<typename T> validate(const T& xmlObject);
```

Then `validate` calls `T::soap_put()` to serialize it and passes the resulting string to `T::soap_get()` deserializing it again, using a freshly generated soap context initialized with the `SOAP_XML_STRICT` flag.

However in practice, upon deserialization, gsoap seems to be unable to recognize the namespace prefixes it generated while serializing, resulting in error messages of the form `"Tags '%s' and '%s' match but namespaces differ`.  I stepped a bit through the validation code in stdsoap2.cpp, which revealed that the failing method `soap_match_namespace()` matches against the soap context property `soap->local_namespaces` which is empty for my freshly constructed de-serializing soap context.

I have no idea how to continue at this point. Is this the expected behavior? How are the `T::soap_put()` and `T::soap_get()` methods supposed to be used anyway? Is there an alternative approach to output validation?

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE?  What does the actual XML content look like?  Perhaps your test has turned up a real issue with the serialized output?

Comment: To me it appears to be very unlikely there is a real issue with the examples I've tested. The setup at hand is unfit and too bloated for an MCVE, I'll have to make one up, but the idea should be clear. Anyway, I don't want you to debug my code and I'm less interested in why my specific setup doesn't work than in these general questions: What is the preferred way of doing it? Is there something wrong with my approach? How does gsoaps validation code actually work? Knowing the answers will help me figure out the solution to the specific case myself.

Comment: If the namespaces do not match, check your .nsmap table and make sure you are using the same Namespace[] table (in .nsmap) for the receiver and sender (since ou're using the same XML lib). There is no other way this can fail but when the Namespace[] bindings somehow differ. Also why bother with output validation since the whole setup is based on a data binding? The only thing left to make sure of are length constraints (e.g. on vectors) but the wsdl2h-generated .h file tells you what these constraints are.

Answer (score 0):

Use the passed in soap object to set the namespaces for your local soap context.

```
template<typename T> validate(struct soap *soap, const T& xmlObject)
{
    struct soap ValidateSoap;

    soap_init(&ValidateSoap);
    soap_set_omode(&ValidateSoap, SOAP_C_UTFSTRING|SOAP_XML_STRICT);
    soap_set_imode(&ValidateSoap, SOAP_C_UTFSTRING|SOAP_XML_STRICT);

    soap_set_namespaces(&ValidateSoap, soap->namespaces);

    ...
}
```